# CSS applied to SVG not functioning

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I have an illustration I made in a graphics program. I named the layers and saved it as SVG.

I put the svg through svgomg to strip the unneccissaries, opened the svg in a code editor and got the information out and into
CodePen where I changed the opacity of some layers, added hover states and @keyframes pulse in CSS.

It works in that environment, but when I try to place it in a page and style/lightly animate it with the same code from CodePen, it is not responding.

The code for the SVG is rather long. For the html, I have the code of the SVG included in php, housed in  tags. The CSS isn't able to apply. I've tried using the straight code of the svg to see if my tag is the problem, as well as trying other tags, but nothing seems to be responding.

Any SVG/CSS people know what I'm doing to stop this from working right? The svg seems to be taking the css in the context of this stack post.

Here is the code

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width:500px;
}
.pulse-center{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s;
}

.pulse-center:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  transition: 1s;
}

.pink-glow {
  opacity:.5;
  transition:1s;
}


@keyframes pulse { /* keyframe animation example */
    0% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: .6;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
}

svg:hover .pink-glow {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .2s;
  animation: 1s pulse infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg class="scorp" viewBox="0 0 341 598" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.5"><path id="Artboard1" style="fill:none" d="M0 0h340.86v597.274H0z"/><clipPath id="_clip1"><path d="M0 0h340.86v597.274H0z"/></clipPath><g clip-path="url(#_clip1)">

<g class="front-legs"><path d="M195.939 536.03s-4.921 19.995 8.039 23.834c12.961 3.839 51.962 3.456 54.069-5.018 0 0 2.695-12.807-8.55-14.424 0 0-39.005 18.341-53.558-4.392Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M195.939 530.6s-12.755-8.841-29.264 0c-16.509 8.84-20.438 24.985-19.175 34.037 1.262 9.052 11.371 17.894 19.175 19.86 7.804 1.966 7.92 2.04 20.84.507l1.614-6.482s-29.35-13.298 6.81-47.922ZM190.884 583.018s-4.795.926 7.66 9.87c12.455 8.944 54.203 4.694 57.296-2.162l1.255-4.654s2.808-5.055-6.94-5.236c-9.748-.182-40.836 18.559-59.271 2.182Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M192.524 580.834s9.872 9.495 18.542 5.238c8.671-4.257 10.099-8.059 17.262-9.029 7.163-.971 14.595 2.983 20.864.405 6.269-2.578 6.45 1.553 8.278 3.386 0 0 5.227-13.811-8.278-16.312-13.505-2.502-25.861-1.952-42.224 4.994-16.362 6.946-17.745-.082-14.444 11.318ZM298.932 592.884s21.257-24.903 20.527-39.607l-.679-16.658s-2.385-4.241-10.805 10.027c-8.421 14.268-19.522 25.068-9.043 46.238Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M261.384 526.671s15.887-5.086 28.411 6.588c14.083 13.128 16.832 6.662 16.832 6.662s3.549-10.239 12.85-7.554c0 0 10.142-.795 11.545 6.656 0 0 1.604-16.138-14.697-16.877 0 0-8.032-1.841-15.834-5.661-7.802-3.821 2.533 1.172 2.533 1.172s-.734-10.749-41.64 9.014Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M322.176 536.03s.245.526.405 14.686c.161 14.16-8.678 31.493-20.883 42.168 0 0 23.525 6.163 32.839-11.776 0 0 9.917-15.081 4.256-21.662 0 0-4.286-10.019-4.143-15.521 0 0-3.979-6.738-12.474-7.895ZM246.646 529.332s11.244-1.977 11.401 6.698c0 0-4.613 9.393 3.337 13.085 0 0 15.981 6.624 22.497 0 6.517-6.625 16.222-6.752.945-13.085-15.277-6.334-19.358-10.426-38.18-6.698ZM287.552 471.064s30.724-46.09 47.567-37.707c0 0 12.737 5.157 5.444 26.19-7.293 21.032-28.917 49.118-37.149 49.108 0 0 7.97-11.209 12.285-22.189 4.314-10.98 5.048-10.501 9.947-21.187 0 0 12.12-19.634-38.094 5.785Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M238.394 523.635c-4.788-1.209 17.367-.753 22.971-11.43 5.605-10.677 17.223-32.061 23.935-32.895 6.713-.834 16.383-.257 16.398 5.307 0 0 3.632 13.213 0 20.104 0 0 2.4 4.103-8.726 4.473 0 0-11.71-.061-18.287 5.545 0 0-14.115 14.498-36.291 8.896ZM201.571 536.03s6.347 17.53 50.247 0c0 0-.731-7.468-14.096-8.118 0 0-15.776-9.356-36.151 8.118ZM270.95 419.188s12.904-3.383 22.022.198c5.929 2.328 13.702 17.7 8.15 29.199 0 0 12.888-16.854 18.654-16.247 0 0-2.532-55.521-48.826-13.15Z" style="fill:#144e07"/><path d="M275.448 407.631s-.01-25.146 10.34-27.774c0 0 15.748-6.219 23.712 7.812 0 0 4.729 7.168-6.419 14.284 0 0-17.846-9.826-27.633 5.678ZM88.02 407.448s-7.521 2.764-12.587 14.997-1.042 12.673-7.092 15.769c-6.05 3.095-19.035 7.865-30.925 12.188-11.89 4.324-18.114 10.077-19.222 28.6-1.109 18.522 6.022 25.178 13.473 22.96 0 0-19.091 14.416-24.579 0-5.488-14.416-13.03-40.482 16.218-58.97 0 0 21.539-17.557 41.423-20.547 19.883-2.99-2.25-14.509 23.291-14.997ZM91.451 467.54s-15.821 7.561-28.493 19.363c-12.672 11.803-26.766 13.212-16.254 27.157 10.512 13.945 24.714 8.419 39.533 36.743l5.214 13.445s6.128-9.91 0-27.206c0 0-11.022-14.027-20.056-23.064-9.033-9.037-4.824-6.759 6.204-17.443 0 0 3.907-4.279 13.852-28.995ZM88.45 393.794s-19.616-46.935-45.424-27.975c0 0-30.39 24.188-21.538 49.756l.435 18.78s-35.159-83.44 38.137-87.011c0 0 22.621-3.687 26.177 23.55 0 0 .407 4.039 2.213 22.9Z" style="fill:#144e07"/></g>

<circle class="pink-glow" cx="192.656" cy="124.916" r="105.411" style="fill:url(#_Radial2)"/>

<g class="tail-stem"><g id="Layer11"><path d="M153.903 240.426s-1.458-10.728-12.382-12.844c-10.924-2.116-13.774 1.538-16.961-2.91-3.187-4.448-7.712-21.917-1.259-35.501 0 0 2.206 3.676 6.961 11.422 4.754 7.746 23.641 39.833 23.641 39.833ZM158.126 231.28c2.044-5.772.199-6.003 2.595-12.836 2.397-6.833 3.974-14.47 7.717-17.066 3.743-2.596 7.836-3.539 12.537-5.393 4.701-1.855 9.593-5.491 10.193-8.693 0 0-4.642-.918-8.319 1.879-3.677 2.797-15.438 4.826-16.174 8.027-.736 3.201 0 5.306 0 5.306l-2.625-1.991s-7.463 10.97-8.153 30.362c0 0-.72 3.056-2.113 4.796 0 0 3.943-3.263 4.342-4.391Z" style="fill:#a8b33f"/><path d="m147.377 227.878-3.966-7.422s-1.796-11.161-1.363-14.93c0 0 2.39 8.879 3.516 11.141 0 0 2.512 7.832 1.813 11.211Z" style="fill:#a8b33f"/></g><path d="M144.004 187.148s2.214-2.317 3.496-3.362c0 0 2.154-8.172 2.614-9.174.459-1.003-1.735-1.906.048-3.894 0 0-.469.758.727 1.081 1.196.324 3.014-.673 3.014-.673l-1.581-1.42s-.088-6.942 1.581-9.078c1.669-2.135 3.342-4.322 4.515-5.793 1.174-1.471 6.117-6.683 6.602-7.526.485-.843 2.639-4.184 2.664-5.59 0 0-2.236 2.435-2.831 3.893 0 0-.561 1.12-1.458.863 0 0-.291-1.08-.805-.773-.514.307-6.244 7.318-7.82 10.243-1.576 2.925-4.841 7.646-4.608 10.438 0 0 .876 3.405 0 2.361a10.416 10.416 0 0 1-1.332-2.008s-.511 7.501-1.33 9.999c-.82 2.498 0 1.026 0 1.026l-1.271-1.995s-3.114 9.919-2.225 11.382Z" style="fill:#a8b33f" id="Layer12"/><path d="M151.183 232.415s.216-3.087-1.93-9.334c-2.145-6.247-2.675-4.237-4.495-11.215-1.819-6.977-2.62-8.964-2.62-11.923 0-2.96-.218-11.12 5.667-15.157l1.746 4.385 1.13-5.632s3.284-5.4 7.568-5.966c4.284-.566 6.105-.454 8.426-.252 0 0 2.567 2.933-1.44 8.284-4.007 5.352-6.15 6.473-6.802 6.874-.653.401-4.53.418-4.53.418l3.16 1.617s-3.638 3.637-4.795 11.732c-1.158 8.095-1.908 7.033-1.146 12.823s2.704 7.75.061 13.346Z" style="fill:#a8b33f" id="Layer2"/><g id="Layer3"><path d="M146.907 177.157s-2.159-17.84-4.77-20.108c-2.61-2.269-3.678-3.005-7.043-1.233-3.365 1.772-4.642 4.545-6.043 3.979l-1.401-.566s-.781 2.227-.178 6.264c.603 4.037-.728 3.713 1.451 5.137 2.18 1.425.843 2.544-1.454 1.253-2.298-1.292-5.615-7.176-4.248-10.34 1.367-3.165 4.311-4.102 4.311-4.102l.466-3.415s13.152-7.762 16.583-2.502c3.431 5.26 5.607 5.807 2.326 25.633ZM150.617 172.911s-1.901.972 2.07 1.041c3.97.068 4.925.299 5.826-2.529.901-2.829 1.51-2.637.356-5.351-1.155-2.713-3.318-4.442-.434-5.884 2.883-1.443 8.24-1.514 8.24-1.514s-8.358-4.732-10.189-1.734c-1.83 2.998-1.918 6.277-1.675 8.219.243 1.941 1.397 5.594 0 6.206-1.397.612-1.593 2.216-4.194 1.546Z" style="fill:#a8b33f"/></g><path d="M227.025 140.044s11.814-.32 17.3 2.78c5.486 3.099 8.004.891 12.135 9.409 4.132 8.518 4.132 10.061 4.132 10.061l3.847 3.556s-1.376-6.763-3.277-10.58c-1.9-3.817-14.934-21.495-34.137-15.226Z" style="fill:#a8b33f" id="Layer9"/><path d="M263.509 169.162s.099-1.837-2.735 3.785c-2.833 5.622-3.567 2.569-3.066 10.924.501 8.354-.073 7.185 1.282 11.185 1.356 4 1.406 4.698 1.406 4.698s-9.224 1.703-12.651.536c-3.427-1.167-8.447-4.744-6.357-11.945 2.09-7.2 3.734-10.208 2.527-13.409-1.207-3.201-1.509-5.007-4.595-3.012 0 0-7.738 4.11-11.249-4.903 0 0-3.84-5.168-3.172-14.906 0 0 1.741-3.757 6.228-5.362 0 0 5.582-.929 6.739-3.321 0 0-1.381 5.126-1.069 10.179.312 5.052 3.014 8.177 4.591 9.341 1.577 1.164 1.926 2.025 1.926 2.025s.904-5.157 8.739-3.961c0 0 .313-2.711 11.456 8.146Z" style="fill:#a8b33f" id="Layer10"/></g>

<g class="tail-flower"><path d="M188.525 119.766s-5.604-7.184-30.107 6.939l-14.809 9.816s-.467 2.166 2.402 1.75c2.868-.416 4.607-3.48 7.892-.122 3.286 3.358 2.04 4.521 5.704 5.775 3.663 1.254 4.136 3.868 5.618.92 1.482-2.948 15.394-17.645 15.394-17.645l-2.672-1.515s2.416-1.006 4.024-1.247c1.608-.241 5.53-3.309 6.554-4.671Z" style="fill:#3a6ff1" id="Layer4"/><path d="M181.714 128.114s-16.045 16.95-15.039 19.473c1.006 2.522 4.956 4.28 6.335 4.773 1.38.493 3.48-6.166 3.48-6.166s-1.459 3.758-.63 6.075c.829 2.317 7.774 3.676 7.774 3.676s3.643 2.185 4.891 1.429c0 0-.564-3.604 0-10.139.563-6.535 1.443-10.564 2.516-12.964 1.073-2.4.943-5.147.943-5.147s-5.73 1.918-10.27-1.01Z" style="fill:#3a6ff1" id="Layer5"/><path d="M199.47 125.601s2.084 2.654 4.368 3.472c2.284.818 3.435 1.248 5.345 1.227 1.91-.022 1.469-1.222 4.941.399 3.473 1.62 3.954 1.979 6.513 2.757 2.56.778 5.465 1.626 6.388.868 0 0 .116 1.597 1.836.347s2.436-2.604 2.436-2.604-1.033.429-1.769-.54c-.737-.968-1.154-1.638-.642-3.413.513-1.775-.211-4.32-1.861-5.498s-3.521-2.813-3.943-1.938c0 0 .218 1.461-.316.925-.534-.535-5.725-10.53-15.998-8.194 0 0-10.309 1.046-9.97 3.807 0 0-.305 2.645 1.959 2.935 2.264.29 4.829-1.073 5.373-.32 0 0 .249 3.376-4.66 5.77Z" style="fill:#3a6ff1" id="Layer7"/><path d="M193.095 128.114s.383 1-1.106 6.873c-1.489 5.874-2.018 10.26-2.308 13.59-.23 2.648.015 12.903 2.308 13.717 0 0 3.528-2.448 5.426-4.761 1.898-2.312 3.723-6.026 5.387-7.837 1.664-1.812.062-2.332 3.155-5.198 3.092-2.865 1.569-2.608 6.802-3.172 5.233-.564 16.893-.106 13.731-5.512 0 0-.225.923-3.042.04-2.816-.882-5.94-4.199-15.65-4.906-.203.71-9.928-2.448-9.299-5.347 0 0-.717 1.238-5.404 2.513Z" style="fill:#3a6ff1" id="Layer6"/></g><path d="M180.851 125.601s1.966 2.228 3.33 2.513c1.365.285 1.999-.856 1.999-.856l.472.856s-.771.763.077.763c.847 0 5.342-.813 6.899-1.559 1.557-.747 7.36-3.774 8.489-5.723 0 0 .193-1.12-1.971-.671 0 0-1.884.107-3.362-1.12 0 0-3.418-1.28-7.172.582 0 0-2.021 1.489-3.778 2.831-1.757 1.342-3.097 2.243-4.983 2.384Z" style="fill:#ffe700" class="flower-center"/>

<path d="M180.851 125.601s1.966 2.228 3.33 2.513c1.365.285 1.999-.856 1.999-.856l.472.856s-.771.763.077.763c.847 0 5.342-.813 6.899-1.559 1.557-.747 7.36-3.774 8.489-5.723 0 0 .193-1.12-1.971-.671 0 0-1.884.107-3.362-1.12 0 0-3.418-1.28-7.172.582 0 0-2.021 1.489-3.778 2.831-1.757 1.342-3.097 2.243-4.983 2.384Z" style="fill:#d93900" class="pulse-center"/> 

<g class="fern"><path id="fernstem" d="M171.724 525.498s30.546-61.603 28.302-98.521c-.65-10.694 2.738-20.131 1.699-27.884-2.534-18.901-4.518-28.126-10.448-43.496-7.376-19.12-11.46-29.315-18.762-43.628-7.301-14.313-17.367-39.475-21.269-54.522" style="fill:none;stroke:#98b7d4;stroke-width:1.67px"/><path d="M180.371 530.6c7.279-9.558 9.593-12.476 14.748-10.204 5.155 2.272 10.984 3.897 10.984 3.897l20.79-12.866-4.884-7.885s72.229-69.42 70.946-80.989c0 0-15.74-4.173-25.359 4.611-9.618 8.783-18.495 19.608-26.296 28.924-7.8 9.315-25.162 23.963-30.178 27.614-5.017 3.652-27.491 37.178-27.491 37.178s-10.54 19.277-3.26 9.72Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer13"/><path d="M191.167 494.084s8.508-17.799 14.25-21.308c5.741-3.509 4.605-.487 9.186-2.234 4.581-1.746 50.846-51.687 52.686-56.568 0 0 .469-7.401-4.655-6.334-5.124 1.066-9.822 10.033-16.569 13.923-6.747 3.89-45.387 46.457-54.898 72.521Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer14"/><path d="M200.454 450.809s1.921-2.04 6.757 0c0 0 3.798-.631 6.437-2.961 2.639-2.33 37.085-37.907 39.215-43.446 0 0 1.657-5.282 1.409-9.267 0 0-.27-1.764-3.662.476-3.392 2.239-7.56 2.218-9.31 5.834-1.749 3.615-16.133 23.02-20.554 25.719-4.422 2.699-17.84 15.536-20.292 23.645Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer15"/><path d="M200.454 430.231s2.944-11.72 11.232-16.231c8.288-4.511 33.421-20.008 34.849-28.487 0 0-7.702-1.105-17.301 4.338-9.599 5.443-26.197 22.344-28.78 40.38Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer16"/><path d="M185.453 494.084s.963-5.391-8.047-4.657-43.018 21.761-48.488 20.89l-10.992-5.364s48.479-24.879 54.366-25.784c5.887-.905 15.115 4.171 13.161 14.915Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer17"/><path d="M191.907 469.584s-3.393-7.652-14.235-7.3c-10.842.352-48.664 31.86-71.295 32.421 0 0-.637.715-.454-6.602.184-7.317 8.091-4.023 12.003-9.037 3.911-5.014 48.635-28.433 54.366-28.257 5.73.177 15.323-2.248 19.615 18.775" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer18"/><path d="M197.454 445.232s5.236.594-5.547.688c-10.784.094-16.33-2.139-19.615-3.326-3.286-1.187-49.875 17.198-58.143 22.766-8.268 5.568-16.56 10.33-16.841 16.706 0 0-8.173-7.648-3.394-15.694 4.779-8.047 27.192-24.146 37.461-27.91 10.268-3.764 39.544-14.536 47.407-8.298 7.863 6.238 11.016 14.265 18.672 15.068Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer19"/><path d="M199.455 413.766s-6.863-4.467-17.782-5.94c-19.116-2.58-44.478 12.676-56.568 19.338-12.09 6.662-33.473 30.942-40.035 33.048-6.563 2.106-24.283-2.878-24.283-2.878s3.99-4.028 7.867-12.105c3.876-8.077 8.333-17.321 18.283-26.112 9.95-8.79 75.287-37.857 112.518-5.351Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer20"/><path d="M201.725 399.093s31.946-26.927 42.382-17.157c0 0-6.266-23.39-19.115-15.144 0 0-14.115 10.062-23.267 32.301Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer21"/><path d="M200.454 394.697s-.793-3.221-9.771-.346c0 0-2.188 4.602-7.392 4.742 0 0-9.681-4.226-23.109-5.612-13.427-1.386-41.755-13.777-64.113 12.182 0 0 2.974-12.576 15.966-16.861 12.992-4.286 52.121-16.56 63.257-6.74 0 0 10.441-1.714 13.672 3.451s9.339 2.614 11.49 9.184Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer22"/><path d="M201.725 385.513s17.835-46.236 42.382-24.624c0 0 6.349 7.212 8.028-1.334 0 0-1.511-3.744-1.322-8.927 0 0 1.802-10.468-6.706-14.965 0 0-8.529-7.253-13.736-4.695 0 0-13.516 3.091-17.405 10.839 0 0-8.78 25.814-11.241 43.706Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer23"/><path d="M196.808 381.936s.514-4.078-7.961-8.613c0 0-15.05-6.588-32.452-3.118-17.402 3.469-31.272 9.63-36.521 11.731-5.248 2.101-17.543 8.674-17.543 8.674s33.139-19.546 39.099-22.886c5.96-3.34 15.298-5.859 19.069-9.757 3.772-3.897 16.554-.714 23.221 4.162 6.668 4.876 12.372 10.962 13.088 19.807Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer25"/><path d="M190.047 357.967s-6.503-7.328-14.755-6.835c-8.252.493-9.374 3.509-16.043 1.301-6.67-2.208-25.375-9.172-35.546-4.985 0 0-12.769 8.865-17.512 8.776-4.742-.09-4.886-3.841-7.167-6.77 0 0 1.915-1.171 8.284-5.321 6.369-4.15 9.618-9.56 17.668-8.573 8.051.987 27.55 2.798 35.476 5.278 7.926 2.481 24.395 7.236 29.595 17.129Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer26"/><path d="M181.09 339.049s-14.256-4.863-33.943-8.627c-19.687-3.765-37.808-.302-40.762 5.02 0 0 1.453-7.53 5.368-11.493 3.915-3.962 7.949-11.078 10.262-10.957 2.313.122.843-.777 11.104 3.062s41.798 11.356 47.971 22.995Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer27"/><path d="M196.814 366.919s12.167-37.276 22.769-40.904c0 0 7.342 1.623 9.404-3.959l2.658-9.075s-7.771-4.343-12.813 0c0 0-21.003 10.308-22.018 53.938Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer28"/><path d="M189.848 348.678s-1.284-15.604 10.606-42.821c4.412-10.098 7.1-8.307 13.776-7.522 3.577.421 2.883 1.784 5.623 1.626l-2.025 7.166c-.371.923-2.36 1.278-3.729 1.118-11.243 7.604-13.965 14.644-24.251 40.433Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer29"/><g id="Layer30"><path d="M181.356 327.008s16.12-33.987 25.767-32.506c0 0-3.251-7.594-7.828-5.013-4.576 2.581-17.429 21.293-17.939 37.519ZM174.3 313.46s7.153-24.674 12.296-24.118c0 0 8.063 4.281 10.301 0 0 0 .369-1.782-3.359-4.454 0 0-9.758-1.675-12.182 1.676-2.453 3.391-7.266 11.848-7.056 26.896Z" style="fill:#738616"/></g><path d="M170.255 316.092s-31.199-12.856-40.706-8.672l-7.303 3.581s6.377-9.994 10.289-10.87c0 0 25.63-3.441 37.72 15.961Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer31"/><path d="M162.486 299.895s-21.863-10.837-25.743-7.921c0 0-5.052.915-5.382-3.104 0 0 .907-3.452 4.392-4.701 0 0 17.126 3.241 26.733 15.726Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer32"/><path d="M167.361 298.965s-.338-10.414 5.154-13.34c0 0 6.001-4.262 11.307-4.474 0 0 1.41-3.026-3.594-4.296 0 0-5.115-2.118-7.713.055-2.597 2.174-7.297 8.049-5.154 22.055Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer33"/><path d="M162.486 286.097s.921-9.434 6.044-12.189c5.123-2.754 6.79-.579 8.373-3.01l1.214-4.8s-15.103-4.491-15.631 19.999Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer34"/><path d="M157.8 288.03s-9.84-8.949-16.229-9.213c0 0-9.665 1.352-13.828 1.103 0 0-4.279-2.556-6.08-.688-1.802 1.868-3.237 3.911-6.609 3.149 0 0 1.301-1.699 5.296-6.445 3.994-4.746 4.326-3.749 9.548-3.43 5.221.319 17.488-1.516 27.902 15.524Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer35"/><path d="M160.333 277.998s1.534-10.806 5.744-14.482c4.21-3.675 6.438-4.375 6.438-4.375s-6.551-3.729-8.348-.52c-1.797 3.208-4.633 11.779-3.834 19.377Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer36"/><path d="M152.78 275.93s-4.734-6.759-10.217-8.272c-5.484-1.512-8.423 1.699-10.221-1.884-1.798-3.582-2.379-5.57-2.379-5.57s1.502-1.019 4.529-.758c3.027.261 12.245 3.627 18.288 16.484Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer37"/><path d="M157.606 268.244s-2.491-5.377 2.181-10.116c4.671-4.739 3.681-3.253 6.22-6.619 2.54-3.365 2.588-4.859 2.588-4.859s-4.283 2.46-7.699 6.333c-3.417 3.874-6.982 6.521-3.29 15.261Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer38"/><path d="M148.865 262.864s-2.844-4.056-8.897-6.91c-6.052-2.855-6.984-2.345-7.36-4.444-.377-2.1-.746-4.191-.746-4.191s14.478 6.183 17.003 15.545Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer39"/><path d="M165.665 521.014s1.039-1.833-9.043-.224c-15.667 2.5-20.449 13.699-28.344 7.012l-13.429-3.147s49.762-26.059 50.816-3.641Z" style="fill:#738616"/><path d="M146.778 253.14s-1.829-2.048-6.415-5.821c-4.585-3.772-4.156-8.254-4.156-8.254s2.25-.894 5.165 2.456c2.914 3.35-1.375-6.743 4.912-11.382 6.288-4.639 7.134-3.904 8.431-7.052 0 0-.961.758 0 7.882s1.141 8.623 0 13.272c-1.141 4.649-2.774 6.954-1.935 8.197.84 1.242.757-4.69 6.58-8.197v3.078s-4.588 5.774-6.58 8.635c-1.992 2.861-2.64 1.441-6.002-2.814Z" style="fill:#738616" id="Layer40"/></g> 

<g class="head-flower"><path d="M203.923 514.999c12.598-9.469 17.816-7.519 21.371.466 3.554 7.986-.349 17.892-4.008 15.995-4.066-2.108-11.009 9.411-14.233 2.231-3.224-7.181 2.259-8.481-2.27-8.713-4.529-.232-13.459-.511-.86-9.979ZM198.852 512.258s9.653-8.067 16.589-11.345c6.935-3.277 10.776-.579 11.239-7.283.464-6.704-10.545-14.47-14.766-12.329-6.556 3.325-22.825 31.877-13.062 30.957Z" style="fill:#f86800"/><path d="M192.839 506.747s11.803-14.132-5.118-18.572c-16.92-4.439-19.717-3.293-22.593 5.616-2.876 8.908-.062 25.261 6.85 19.383 7.419-6.308 4.012 3.718 19.089.849M186.014 520.716s-.639-6.666-9.434 0c-8.795 6.667-14.579.733-17.231 7.731-2.651 6.997 2.246 21.323 9.261 19.37 15.19-4.231 10.179-20.775 17.404-27.101ZM188.013 525.524c.939-2.55 6.96 2.081 9.398-1.021 1.189.7 3.343 4.698 3.922 5.893 1.248 2.576 8.073 6.281 6.312 14.552-1.761 8.272-10.936 11.082-13.843 11.412-2.908.33-14.77-6.436-5.789-30.836Z" style="fill:#f86800"/><path d="M194.338 511.079s-1.238 2.408-.704 4.528c0 0 .64 2.072 2.646 1.138 0 0-1.058-.086-.997 2.08.061 2.165.997 2.88.997 2.88s-1.944 2.172-4.039 1.897c0 0-3.868-.539-4.667-3.375 0 0 .428-3.237-1.56-4.347 0 0-1.048-.52 2.208-.103 3.257.417 3.476.857 6.116-4.698Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear3)"/></g>

<g class="arm-flower"><path d="M76.659 393.161c-22.689-14.55-32.402-11.892-39.377-.235-6.974 11.658-4.537 29.93 3.704 31.38 8.241 1.45 16.113 3.094 22.436-7.387 6.322-10.481 5.333-13.761 13.686-13.909 8.352-.148 22.239 4.7-.449-9.849ZM89.025 395.107s-14.067-9.662-24.174-14.438-15.704-.845-16.379-10.614c-.676-9.769.235-26.071 7.037-24.935 6.803 1.137 32.958 31.408 33.516 49.987ZM94.86 383.926s-17.199-20.594 7.459-27.063c24.658-6.469 28.733-4.8 32.924 8.182 4.192 12.982.091 36.813-9.982 28.248-10.811-9.193-16.817-2.762-21.412 0-2.536 1.524-5.426-3.702-6.61 0M104.806 404.284s.933-9.715 13.749 0 12.079 6.585 15.943 16.783c3.864 10.198 4.028 25.908 0 29.791-9.386 9.048-19.162-37.356-29.692-46.574ZM101.893 411.29c-1.368-3.716-7.998 1.72-11.55-2.801-1.732 1.02-2.294 5.32-3.138 7.062-1.819 3.753-16.487 11.991-13.921 24.045 2.567 12.054 15.937 16.149 20.174 16.63 4.237.481 21.524-9.379 8.435-44.936Z" style="fill:#ffce00"/><path d="M92.676 390.239s1.804 3.509 1.026 6.599c0 0-.932 3.02-3.856 1.659 0 0 1.542-.125 1.453 3.03-.089 3.155-1.453 4.197-1.453 4.197s2.834 3.166 5.886 2.765c0 0 5.637-.786 6.802-4.919 0 0-.624-4.717 2.272-6.334 0 0 1.529-.758-3.217-.15-4.747.608-5.066 1.249-8.913-6.847Z" style="fill:url(#_Linear4)"/></g></g><defs><linearGradient id="_Linear3" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="scale(-8.60107 8.60107) rotate(72.104 -52.343 14.435)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0577c4;stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#060708;stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="_Linear4" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="rotate(72.104 -224.597 261.84) scale(12.53418)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#0577c4;stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#060708;stop-opacity:1"/></linearGradient><radialGradient id="_Radial2" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="scale(100.7442) rotate(-34.621 3.003 -2.41)"><stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#fa33aa;stop-opacity:1"/><stop offset=".54" style="stop-color:#fe34b3;stop-opacity:.28"/><stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#ff34b7;stop-opacity:0"/></radialGradient></defs></svg>
```

epen, in case that helps.

https://codepen.io/SavBeck/pen/zYzeBoj

Thank you kindly.

Comment: So are you saying that it is working as desired here on your post and Codepen BUT that it is not working in your environment?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. I am surprised it worked here.

Comment: Do you have any ideas for me to try?

Comment: Your animation is triggered by hovering the SVG. What happens when it does not depend on hover? `svg .pink-glow { ... }`

Comment: You may be having issues with pointer-events ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @Ruskin I tried applying 
pointer-events: all;
pointer-events: stroke; 
pointer-events: fill;

to the <object> holding my SVG, hoping it would trickel down to everything inside there. I also tried applying those SVG pointer events to the class for each layer I want to activate, but it's still all "on" all the time. 

Do you have any other ideas for me to try? Or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I also tried adding this into the svg, after the <svg>, but before the <g>'s.

<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" type="text/css"/>

Comment: @PaulLeBeau do you know what I should do?